# Lining up sharing buttons on webpage [Facebook, Twitter, Pinterest and Google +]

Tags: html, css

I'm working on a blog page template in Shopify and having a real tough time trying to figure out why the Facebook share button won't line up vertically with the other share buttons? It appears the Facebook button is 5px lower than the others.
[image: Misaligned sharing buttons]

The Facebook share button code is:

```
<div style='margin-top: -5px;'
class="fb-share-button"
data-href="MY URL"
data-layout="button_count"
data-mobile-iframe="true"></div>
```

As you can see I have tried applying an inline style to line up the buttons, however it doesn't have any effect. I'm sure other people have come across this problem. Any ideas?

Cheers, DB.

Comment: Have you tried `vertical-align: top;`? It's hard to see exactly what's going on without all the relevant code.

Comment: Work's like a charm, thank you @HunterTurner

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Add `vertical-align: top;` to your div.

```
<div style='vertical-align: top;'
class="fb-share-button"
data-href="MY URL"
data-layout="button_count"
data-mobile-iframe="true"></div>
```

You can read more about vertical-align [here](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/vertical-align).